# How to construct my mixed integer programming problem with constraint of minimum consecutive ones

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, binary-variable

My target is to formulate a binary sequence with fixed size $N$ = 10, such as $[1, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]$. However, I want to constrain this sequence so that when 1 appears, it has to appear at least three times; This is partial problem when I formulate my traffic signal optimization problem, in which 1/0 indicates green/red. I need to add such constraint to emulate minimum green time in the real world.

Answer (score 8):

Define a two sets of binary variables : variables $x_i$ take value $1$ if and only if the $i^{th}$ term of the sequence equals $1$, and variable $y$ that takes value $1$ if and only if one of the terms equals $1$.

You want to enforce

$$
y=1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sum_i{x_i} \ge 3 \\
x_i = 1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y=1 
$$

You can do this with
\begin{align*}
3 y &\le \sum_i{x_i} \\
x_i &\le y \quad \forall i
\end{align*}

---

It is not clear in your question if the ones have to be consecutive or not. If they do, then you need to forbid all the patterns that do not satisfy this. @ErwinKalvelagen shows us how to achieve this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008969/binary-variables-in-time-series-integer-linear-programming):

> One simple way to enforce a run length of at least three, is to forbid
> patterns `010` and `0110`. This can be modeled as:
>
> $$ -x_t + x_{t+1} - x_{t+2} \le 0 $$
>
> and
>
> $$ -x_t + x_{t+1} + x_{t+2} - x_{t+3} \le 1 $$
>
> A little bit of thought is needed to decide what to do at the borders,
> especially the first time period.
>
> A different approach is detailed
> [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/03/production-scheduling-minimum-up-time.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. Sorry for the unclear question. The ones must be consecutive in my problem. From my understanding, probably defining variable set of _x~i_ is not necessary since _xi_ would be identical to the original sequence.

Comment: yes correct, variables $x_i$ are certainly already defined.

Comment: But thank you for sharing the link. The problem the link leads to is just like my problem.