# How to make a constraint for consecutive zeros in the mixed integer programming problems

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, binary-variable

I intend to generate a binary sequence with a size of $N = 10$, for example, $[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]$. The constraint is that when zero appears, it must appear for at least two consecutive times, such as $[1, 0, 0, 1] $ or $[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]$. In contrast, $[1, 0, 1]$ is not good since zero has appeared for only one time. Previously I have asked a similar question with minimum consecutive one requirement [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7403/how-to-construct-my-mixed-integer-programming-problem-with-constraint-of-minimum). But this time the requirement is changed into zeros. I know I can simply define a new variable which convert this "zeros" constraint to "ones" constraint. But I am curious how mathematical formulations will vary.

Comment: Just substitute $1-x_i$ for $x_i$ in the answer to your previous question.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you for your response. But the previous question has a constraint that requires three consecutive ones. But this problem has the constraint for two consecutive zeros. I think I need more revision than replacing 1-xi.

Comment: @prubin Thank you very much. It works by adding 1- towards x_i and x_i-1 and other relevant variables. Sorry, that I did not fully capture your point.